# trying to run this code but i keep getting an error saying "incorrect syntax near keyword 'where'" please assist

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert-update

```
        If _id <> String.Empty Then
            cn.Open()
            cm = New SqlCommand("update tblBill_Items set description = @description,qty = @qty,unitprice=@unitiprice,discount=@discount WHERE id=@id AND invoiceno=@invoiceno", cn)
            With cm.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("description", TextBox9.Text)
                .AddWithValue("qty", CDbl(TextBox8.Text))
                .AddWithValue("unitprice", CDbl(TextBox7.Text))
                .AddWithValue("discount", CDbl(TextBox6.Text))
                .AddWithValue("id", _id)
                .AddWithValue("invoiceno", TextBox4.Text)
            End With
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()

        Else

            cn.Open()
            cm = New SqlCommand("insert into tblBill_Items (invoiceno,description,qty,unitprice,discount) values(@invoiceno,@description,@qty,@unitprice,@discount)", cn)
            With cm.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("invoiceno", TextBox4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("description", TextBox9.Text)
                .AddWithValue("qty", CDbl(TextBox8.Text))
                .AddWithValue("unitprice", CDbl(TextBox7.Text))
                .AddWithValue("discount", CDbl(TextBox6.Text))
            End With
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
        End If
```

Comment: The code in your question should not cause that error. Do you perhaps have a trigger on the table using dynamic SQL?

Comment: By the way you should dispose your connection and command objects with `using`. [Also specify parameter types and lengths explicitly](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Could it be that `_id` is `Nothing`, in which case it will execute the THEN part?

Comment: You need to divid and conquer. Add a breakpoint and check the values that are being passed. If they are all correct take the statment and run it directly in SSMS with the actual values. If that doesn't yield any clues, reduce the statement to the most basic possible and confirm it works, then add to it bit by bit.

Comment: OT: there's a lot of duplication of code there. You only need to open the connection once, create the command once, create five of the parameters once, execute the query once and close the connection once. The only things that are different is the `CommandText` of the command and one parameter, so that's all that should be within the `If...Else`. Also, you should create a new connection object with a `Using` statement and it will be implicitly closed at the end of the block. Finally, call `Add` and specify the data type explicitly rather than calling `AddWithValue`.

Comment: What catches my eye is AddWithValue.  Just be aware, this can do an implicit and sometime very unexpected type cast on the parameter.  I see _id is a String, what type is corresponding DB field? https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You need to check  ```textbox4.text``` should not be empty . I suggest to convert Id  to long or Double

Comment: You should write your queries in [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) first using DECLARE for required parameters then use that query in code which would handle syntax issues.

For adding parameters, better to use [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_) than AddWithValue.

Comment: Also provide better names for input controls and validate values prior to using the values for parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP, the data types for the database columns weren't provided which would have been rather useful. I'll go over some potential issues with your code. I say "potential" because without knowing the data types for the database columns and without having some sample input for the Form, it's not possible to know for sure where some of the issues may lie.

It's possible that an issue is occurring due to `AddWithValue`. You may consider using `Add` instead and explicitly specifying the data type-which is used in the code below. If the value in one of the TextBoxes is null or empty this will be an issue. In this case, it's necessary to set the value as `DBNull.Value`.

Both `_id <> String.Empty` and `.AddWithValue("id", _id)` seem to indicate that the `id` column is a string data type such as `varchar` or `nvarchar`. However, in your insert statement, `id` wasn't specified:

```
cm = New SqlCommand("insert into tblBill_Items (invoiceno,description,qty,unitprice,discount) values(@invoiceno,@description,@qty,@unitprice,@discount)", cn)
```

When a value is autoincremented upon insertion, it isn't necessary to specify the column during the insertion so it's possible that the data type is a decimal that autoincrements which makes it a good candidate to be the primary key. However, `invoiceno` should also be unique, which makes it a good candidate to be the primary key. Personally, I would eliminate the `id` column and use `invoiceno` as the primary key. However, in the code below, I've made `id` the primary key and made `invoiceno` unique, as this is another viable option.

There doesn't seem to be any checking to see if any of the values from the Textboxes are null or empty, although it's possible that this was done in code that wasn't included in the OP. There doesn't seem to be any checking to ensure that a value is numeric prior to converting it to a numeric value. What happens if `TextBox8.Text` contains `abc`?

```
CDbl(TextBox8.Text)
```

You may consider using `Double.TryParse` or `Decimal.TryParse` instead.

In the update SQL statement, `WHERE id=@id AND invoiceno=@invoiceno` it doesn't seem necessary to include both `id` and `invoiceno` since they are both likely unique values.

---

The following shows how to create a table in SQL Server using VB.NET. It also shows how to both insert data and update data in the table. The code has been tested using SQL Express.

- **Database name**: Order
- **Table name**: tblBill_items

**Note**: The connection string needs to be modified for your environment. See [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) for more information. The table name was taken from the OP.

In the code below, the `id` column (in the database table) is decimal and autoincrements. Additionally, `invoiceno` is unique.

**Create a new `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` project**

**Add a module** (name: Helper.vb)

**Helper.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Helper
 
    'ToDo: modify the connection string for your environment
    Private connectionStr As String = String.Format("Data Source='.\SQLExpress'; Initial Catalog='Order'; Integrated Security=True")

    Public Sub CreateTblBillItems()
        Dim sqlText As String = "CREATE TABLE tblBill_Items (id decimal NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
                                          CONSTRAINT PK_tblBill_Items_id PRIMARY KEY,
                                          invoiceno nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
                                          CONSTRAINT UQ_tblBill_Items_invoiceno UNIQUE,
                                          description nvarchar(50),
                                          qty decimal NOT NULL,
                                          unitprice decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
                                          discount decimal(18,2))"

        ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText As String)

        Try
            Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
                'open
                cn.Open()

                Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlText, cn)
                    'execute
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (SqlException): " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExecuteNonQueryTblBillItems(sqlText As String, invoiceNo As String, description As String, qty As Double, unitPrice As Decimal, discount As Decimal, Optional id As Decimal = 0)

        Try
            Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
                'open
                cn.Open()

                Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlText, cn)

                    With cmd.Parameters
                        .Add("@id", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = id
                        .Add("@invoiceno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceNo), DBNull.Value, invoiceNo)
                        .Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(description), DBNull.Value, description)
                        .Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = qty
                        .Add("@unitprice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = unitPrice
                        .Add("@discount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = discount
                    End With

                    'ToDo: remove the following code that is for debugging
                    'For Each p As SqlParameter In cmd.Parameters
                    'Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName & ": " & p.Value.ToString())
                    'Next

                    'execute
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (SqlException): " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub InsertTblBillItems(invoiceNo As String, description As String, qty As Double, unitPrice As Decimal, discount As Decimal)
        Dim sqlText As String = "INSERT INTO tblBill_Items(invoiceno, description, qty, unitprice, discount) VALUES(@invoiceno, @description, @qty, @unitprice, @discount)"
        ExecuteNonQueryTblBillItems(sqlText, invoiceNo, description, qty, unitPrice, discount)
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateTblBillItems(invoiceNo As String, description As String, qty As Double, unitPrice As Decimal, discount As Decimal, id As Decimal)
        Dim sqlText As String = "UPDATE tblBill_Items set invoiceno = @invoiceno, description = @description, qty = @qty, unitprice = @unitprice, discount = @discount WHERE invoiceno = @invoiceno"
        ExecuteNonQueryTblBillItems(sqlText, invoiceNo, description, qty, unitPrice, discount, id)
    End Sub
End Module
```

On Form1, add the Button, Label, and TextBox controls as shown below:

[image]

Double-click each of the buttons to add the "Click" event handler.

**Form1.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private id As Decimal = 0
    Private invoiceNo As String = String.Empty
    Private description As String = String.Empty
    Private qty As Double = 0
    Private unitPrice As Decimal = 0
    Private discount As Decimal = 0

    Private Sub ButtonCreateTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCreateTable.Click
        Helper.CreateTblBillItems()

        Debug.WriteLine("Info: Table 'tblBill_Items' created")
    End Sub

    Private Function IsInputAvailable() As Boolean

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxInvoiceNo.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("InvoiceNo not specified", "Error - InvoiceNo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxDescription.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Description not specified", "Error - Description", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxQty.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Qty not specified", "Error - Qty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxUnitPrice.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("UnitPrice not specified", "Error - UnitPrice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Sub GetData()
        'get/set values

        'try to convert
        Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxId.Text, id)

        invoiceNo = TextBoxInvoiceNo.Text.Trim()
        description = TextBoxDescription.Text.Trim()
        qty = 0
        unitPrice = 0
        discount = 0

        'convert to Double
        Double.TryParse(TextBoxQty.Text, qty)

        'convert to Decimal
        Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxUnitPrice.Text, unitPrice)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxDiscount.Text) Then
            'convert to Decimal
            Decimal.TryParse(TextBoxDiscount.Text, discount)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInsert.Click

        If IsInputAvailable() Then
            GetData()
            Helper.InsertTblBillItems(invoiceNo, description, qty, unitPrice, discount)

            Debug.WriteLine("Info: Data inserted into 'tblBill_Items'")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUpdate.Click
        If IsInputAvailable() Then
            GetData()
            Helper.UpdateTblBillItems(invoiceNo, description, qty, unitPrice, discount, id)

            Debug.WriteLine("Info: Table 'tblBill_Items' updated")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Resources**:

- [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)
- [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
- [SqlCommand Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
- [SqlParameter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
- [Description of the database normalization basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description)

Comment: All though a very complete tutorial, how exactly does this answer the original question?  Not meaning to cause offense, but copy and paste boiler plate code with no explanation IMO is just a invention for misuse by the uninformed

Comment: @Hursey: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the post to start out by discussing possible issues with the code in the OP, before showing a working solution.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBill_Items](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [invoiceno] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [qty] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 [unitprice] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 [discount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 [total] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblBill_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: Thanks for providing the table definition. However, it seems that you are missing some code at the end, after "CLUSTERED", that specifies the column(s) for the primary key.

Comment: Thanks mate i managed to resolve the problem

Comment: @MastoLiquid-MindNtuboy: If this post helped you in resolving your issue, please consider marking it as the answer. If the post didn't help in resolving your issue, it would be beneficial to the community if you mentioned what you discovered the issue to be and how you resolved it.

Comment: Technically if it was useful in resolving it should be upvoted, but the actual solution should be posted as an answer by the OP and then self-accepted

Answer (score -4):

If _id field is a string and your query is expecting an actual string value you should wrap it in single quotes

Comment: It's parameterized so this is not relevant