# In VB.NET how to use id from SQL Server to update the table if id is not returned in form directly

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update, database-connection

This is the code I got, but using this I cannot update `custname`. I need to use id in this which is autoincremented in database.

```
con2.Open()

Dim query As String
query = "update CustomerMaster set CustName='" + TextBox1.Text + "',Address='" + TextBox2.Text + "',Phone='" + TextBox3.Text + "',Mobile='" + TextBox4.Text + "',email='" + TextBox5.Text + "'where  CustName='" + TextBox1.Text + "'"

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con2)

Dim reader2 As SqlDataReader
reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader

MessageBox.Show("Data updated")
con2.Close()
```

[image: snap]

This is a snap from a Youtube video in this they use datagrid view but in my form it is listbox so can anyone convert this code to use in listbox

Actually I want to find the id in vb.net which is invisible and only can see in sql server.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the code from the image as text so that those of us who can't see the picture clearly can read it as text.

Comment: Oh, so whatever YT video you're following, it shows a wrong way (an "anti-pattern") of interacting with a database for .NET. Note the video's author and don't follow them any more - they are 30 years out of date.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355687/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483410/how-do-i-correct-a-syntax-error-in-command-builder/70484316#70484316 (this one can be adapted for SQL Server).

Comment: The id should have been retrieved when you retrieved the data from the database. However, it's not necessary to display the id to the user.

Comment: You should be using a data adapter and a `DataTable`. Call `Fill` to populate the `DataTable` with data including the PK values, make as many edits as you require and then call `Update` to save the changes. The control(s) that you bind your `DataTable` to are irrelevant to that.

Comment: The screenshot you have posted shows a `SELECT` statement being executed by calling `ExecuteNonQuery` and your code executes am `UPDATE` statement by calling `ExecuteReader`, both of which are backwards. You're also being shown how to build SQL code using string concatenation, which is bad. I agree that you should never watch anything from that person again and find a proper ADO.NET tutorial.

Comment: actually i want to find id which is not visible in the form ,but only in sql

Comment: You can't use something that you don't have. If you want to use the id in your program, ensure that you've retrieved the id from the database when you retrieve the data from your database. You  may consider using a  [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) as others have suggested.

Comment: The following may also be helpful: [DataSets, DataTables, and DataViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/) and [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8).