# Adding Parameters to Commands VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am running into issues using parameters in VB.NET. This is my first attempt doing so, I Never ran into any issues using C#.

Please bear with me as this might be a rookie mistake.

It is as if the parameters are not being declared. It is not registering the values.

```
If ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text = "Unassigned + Current" Then
            Query = "SELECT REC.Folder, REC.File_Name, REC.Receipt_ID, REC.Amount, REC.Description, REC.Transaction_Date, REC.Rotate, REC.Num_In_Group, EXP.Approval, EXP.Approval_Employee_ID "
            Query &= "FROM Receipts REC "
            Query &= "INNER JOIN Expense_Receipts ER ON ER.Receipt_ID = REC.Receipt_ID "
            Query &= "INNER JOIN Expenses EXP on EXP.Expense_ID = ER.Expense_ID AND EXP.Statement_Identifier = @ses "
            Query &= "WHERE REC.Employee_ID = @user "
            Query &= "AND REC.Status > 0 "
            Query &= "AND REC.Sequence = 1 "
            Query &= "AND ({ fn LENGTH(REC.File_Name) } >= 9) "
            Query &= "UNION "
            Query &= "SELECT Folder, File_Name, Receipt_ID, Amount, Description, Transaction_Date, Rotate, Num_In_Group, NULL as Approval, Null as Approval_Employee_ID "
            Query &= "FROM Receipts "
            Query &= "WHERE Employee_ID = @user "
            Query &= "AND Receipt_ID NOT IN (Select Receipt_ID from Expense_Receipts) "
            Query &= "AND Receipt_ID NOT IN (Select Receipt_ID from Expense_Report_Receipts) "
            Query &= "AND Status > 0 "
            Query &= "AND Sequence = 1 "
            Query &= "AND ({ fn LENGTH(File_Name) } >= 9) "
            Query &= "ORDER BY Transaction_Date"

        ElseIf ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text = "Unassigned" Then
            Query = "SELECT Folder, File_Name, Receipt_ID, Amount, Description, Transaction_Date "
            Query &= ", Rotate, Num_In_Group, NULL as Approval, NULL as Approval_Employee_ID "
            Query &= "FROM Receipts  "
            Query &= "WHERE Employee_ID = @user "
            Query &= "AND Receipt_ID NOT IN (Select Receipt_ID from Expense_Receipts) "
            Query &= "AND Receipt_ID NOT IN (Select Receipt_ID from Expense_Report_Receipts) "
            Query &= "AND Status > 0 "
            Query &= "AND Sequence = 1 "
            Query &= "AND ({ fn LENGTH(File_Name) } >= 9) "
            Query &= "ORDER BY Transaction_Date"

        ElseIf ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text = "Current Statement" Then
            Query = "SELECT REC.Folder, REC.File_Name, REC.Receipt_ID, REC.Amount, REC.Description, REC.Transaction_Date, REC.Rotate, REC.Num_In_Group, EXP.Approval, EXP.Approval_Employee_ID "
            Query &= "FROM Receipts REC "
            Query &= "INNER JOIN Expense_Receipts ER ON ER.Receipt_ID = REC.Receipt_ID "
            Query &= "INNER JOIN Expenses EXP on EXP.Expense_ID = ER.Expense_ID AND EXP.Statement_Identifier = @ses "
            Query &= "WHERE REC.Employee_ID = @user "
            Query &= "AND REC.Status > 0 "
            Query &= "AND REC.Sequence = 1 "
            Query &= "AND ({ fn LENGTH(File_Name) } >= 9) "
            Query &= "ORDER BY REC.Transaction_Date"
        End If

        Try
            Make_Connection(Query)
            oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader
            'DDL User
            'oCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlUser.SelectedValue.ToString
            'Session 
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@ses", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            oCmd.Parameters("@ses").Value = Session("SELECT REC.Folder, REC.File_Name, REC.Receipt_ID, REC.Amount, REC.Description, REC.Transaction_Date, REC.Rotate, REC.Num_In_Group, EXP.Approval, EXP.Approval_Employee_ID ")
            oCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT REC.Folder, REC.File_Name, REC.Receipt_ID, REC.Amount, REC.Description, REC.Transaction_Date, REC.Rotate, REC.Num_In_Group, EXP.Approval, EXP.Approval_Employee_ID FROM Receipts REC INNER JOIN Expense_Receipts ER ON ER.Receipt_ID = REC.Receipt_ID INNER JOIN Expenses EXP on EXP.Expense_ID = ER.Expense_ID AND EXP.Statement_Identifier = @ses WHERE REC.Employee_ID = @user AND REC.Status > 0 AND REC.Sequence = 1 AND ({ fn LENGTH(File_Name) } >= 9) ORDER BY REC.Transaction_Date ", MyConn)
            Dim param = New SqlParameter
            param.ParameterName = "@City"
            param.Value = ddlUser.SelectedValue.toString()
            oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader
            Try
                While oReader.Read
```

I have attempted to use a using statement. I attached the rough thrown together code.

All was working before attempting to switch to parameters.

```
Using oCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, MyConn)
            MyConn.Open()
            'oCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlUser.SelectedValue.ToString
            'Session 
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@ses", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            oCmd.Parameters("@ses").Value = Session("Current_Statement_Identifier")
            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MyConn.Close()
        End Using'DDL User
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            oCmd.Parameters("@user").Value = ddlUser.SelectedValue.ToString
            'Session 
            oCmd.Parameters.Add("@ses", SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

I'm also attaching my `Make_Connection` sub in case I'm looking past the issue here.

```
Public Sub Make_Connection(ByVal SQLText As String)

        Try
            MyConn = New SqlConnection("******")
            oCmd = MyConn.CreateCommand
            oCmd.CommandText = SQLText
            If MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: What issues? Please be more specific.

Comment: Its like the parameter is not being declared. I have been debugging via labels

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355687/10024425

Comment: You've not mentioned what your DB is here you're querying.  Are you sure that using a parameter in a join statement is syntaxial correct for your DB engine?  Have you tried running these SQL statements direct via the DB Engine tools?  There is not real difference in doing this via either vb.net or C#.  Also do some reading on string builders, and your SQL connections should also be wrapped in a Using block

Comment: You may be falling through the If statement. Add an Else statement after the last elseif to alert you that no match was found.

Answer (score 0):

This is boiler plate code the method is InertSSData and it gets called from
a button click

```
   Private Sub InsertSSData()

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            Try
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SSDataTable (ssAmount,ssType,ssDesc) VALUES (@ssAmount,@ssType,@ssDesc)"

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ssAmount", DbType.String).Value = tbDepositAmt.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ssType", DbType.String).Value = tbDepositType.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ssDesc", DbType.String).Value = tbDepositDesc.Text.Trim
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception
                tbMessage.Text = "SSData Table Failed"
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Here is reading values and putting the data in a DataGridView

```
               Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvTX.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above is when DB is bound to dgvTX
                '============================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("TID")))
                    strDate = rdr("txSortDate").ToString
                    strTxType = rdr("txType").ToString
                    strAmt = CDec(rdr("txAmount"))
                    strCKNum = rdr("txCKNum").ToString
                    strDesc = rdr("txDesc").ToString
                    strBal = CDec(rdr("txBalance"))
                    dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                    'dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"'Adds the $ sign and commas
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(intID, strDate, strTxType, strAmt, strCKNum, strDesc, strBal, emptyStr)

                    rowCount = rowCount + 1

                End While

                dgvTX.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                dgvTX.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N"
                dgvTX.Sort(dgvTX.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
            End Using

            If rowCount <= 25 Then
                maxRowCount = 25 - rowCount
                For iA = 1 To maxRowCount
                    dgvTX.Rows.Add(" ")
                Next
            End If


            lblAmt.Text = $"Current Balance  {Date.Today:MMMM d yyyy}"
            Dim dateToday = Date.Today
            Dim lblDate As String = dateToday.ToString("MMM" & " " & "d" & " " & "yyyy")
            lblAmt.Text = "Current Balance  " & lblDate

            GetCBBalance()

            tbBal.Text = "$ " & String.Format("{0:n}", strTotalBal)

        End Using
```